# Error to clone controller form contact

Tags: magento2

hello I cloned the contact form controller to customize some fields but when sending data I get the following error, I think it is due to the constructor:

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Esign\Contact\Controller\Magento\Contact\Index\Post\Interceptor

Comment: please share full code

Comment: Please share the code which you have do.

Answer (score 0):

Hi now i have this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isEnabled() on null in /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index.php:64 Stack trace:

```
<?php

namespace Esign\Contact\Controller\Magento\Contact\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface; 
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
    

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
{

/**
 * @var DataPersistorInterface
 */
private $dataPersistor;

/**
 * @var Context
 */
private $context;

/**
 * @var LoggerInterface
 */
private $logger;

/**
 * @var MailInterface
 */
private $mail;
/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param ConfigInterface $contactsConfig
 * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
    MailInterface $mail,
    DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
    LoggerInterface $logger = null
) {
    
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $this->context = $context;
    $this->mail = $mail;
    $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
    $this->logger = $logger ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
}

public function execute()
{
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
    }
    try {
        $this->sendEmail($this->validatedParams());
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
            __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
        );
        $this->dataPersistor->clear('contact_us');
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
            __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
        );
        //$this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
    }
}

/**
 * @param array $post Post data from contact form
 * @return void
 */
private function sendEmail($post)
{
    $this->mail->send(
        $post['email'],
        ['data' => new DataObject($post)]
    );
}
/**
 * @return array
 * @throws \Exception
 */
private function validatedParams()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if (trim($request->getParam('name')) === '') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the Name and try again.'));
    }
    if (trim($request->getParam('comment')) === '') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the comment and try again.'));
    }
    if (false === \strpos($request->getParam('email'), '@')) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('The email address is invalid. Verify the email address and try again.'));
    }
    if (trim($request->getParam('hideit')) !== '') {
        throw new \Exception();
    }

    return $request->getParams();
}

}
```

Comment: This should have just been an edit to your original post.